# Nested transaction in Spring app with JPA (postgres)

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, transactions

Is it possible to have `PROPAGATION_NESTED` in `@Transactional()` with JPA using **postgres**? I am getting:

```
org.springframework.transaction.NestedTransactionNotSupportedException:
JpaDialect does not support savepoints - check your JPA provider's capabilities
```

I tried:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory()
                .getObject());
    transactionManager.setNestedTransactionAllowed(true);
    return transactionManager;
}
```

But with no success.

Comment: Which JPA implementation are you using?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using Hibernate. NESTED transactions is not possible with Hibernate.

[image]

In the following code excerpt, spring sets savePointManager. But there is no class implementing `SavepointManager` in Hibernate.

Comment: Yes, I do use Hibernate. Ah, that's too bad. Suppose I will move from Hibernate to something else

Answer (score -2):

`savepointAllowed` is true, it means Transaction manager allow nested transactions. But `JpaDialect` does not support savepoints.